# How to add apostrophes spaces and dashes in regex pattern and avoid they're next to each other

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to set a regex validation pattern as to validate a string imput from user

The string should begins with a number (between 1 and 99999) followed by a name (can contain only uppercase or lowercase letters, dashes ('-'), apostrophes ( '') or spaces( '') And numbers. Dashes characters, apostrophes and spaces can not be next to each other (have to be seperated by somethin else) .

So far I'm trying this

```
/^[0-9999a-zA-Z ]*$/
```

I'm lost on the part of how to add apostrophes , spaces and numbers and make sure they're not be next to each other (have to be separated by something else) .

Much appreciation

Comment: Try [`^\d{1,5}(?!.*([' -])\1)[\p{L}\d' -]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/wB3yQ8/1). You say *between 1 and 99999*, but the regex you tried shows a range from 0 to 9999 (used incorrectly, but I see what you intend to achieve).

Comment: is there a reason you didn't add this as an answer? Looks good to me.

Comment: @Charlie: *Dashes characters, apostrophes and spaces can not be together.* and *how to add apostrophes , spaces and numbers and make sure they're not together* clash. I do not post when the question is not 100% clear.

Comment: Makes sense - I'm just trying to learn from the pros.

Comment: Oh, a lot of people post whatever comes to their minds, and sometimes they even hit the bull's eye.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm very sorry to be not clear , I wanted the Dashes characters, apostrophes and spaces can not be nex to each other ! omg I'm sorry

Comment: Ok, "dashes characters" are just dashes, I believe. Could you provide any valid and invalid strings to test against? However, you have an answer that covers ASCII letters and the `1-9999` range (not `0-9999`). Please check if it is enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your concern here is an exemple of a valid string 99999-sTr e't  , also valide 99999 sTr-e't  , now an invalid : 99999-str e'-t  (if u notice the ' and - are next to each other)

Comment: Aha, so that means you need something like [`^\d{1,5}(?!.*[' -]{2})[\p{L}\d' -]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/wB3yQ8/3)? The answer below is quite **valid** then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you Wiktor , sorry to be not clear from start , I've ben coding since this morning . Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regexp:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[1-9][0-9]{0,4}(?!.*[ '-]{2})[0-9a-zA-Z '-]+$");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("197zA1z2-8'7").find()); // returns true
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("1zA1 2-8'7").find()); //returns true
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("1zA1 2- 8'7").find()); //returns false
```

Comment: Just a pet peeve: the second `.*` after the `{2}` is rather redundant. Use `"^[1-9][0-9]{0,4}(?!.*[ '-]{2})[0-9a-zA-Z '-]+$"`.

Comment: Thanks! Very much appreciated

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the remark, I updated my answer in consequence